# Recently downloaded files using wget

Tags: ubuntu, wget

How to find a list of recently modified files on the Ubuntu server 18.04? Specifically, I need a list of recently downloaded files using `wget`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have used `wget` command to  download files, you can check `history` command to list out  all the previously used commands  and use `grep "wget"` to list out whenever wget command was used.

```
history | grep "wget" | grep -E "(\-[PO])|(\-\-output-document|\-\-directory-prefix)"
```

here: `"(\-[PO])|(\-\-output-document|\-\-directory-prefix)"` means `grep` any of the following below

- `-P` or `--directory-prefix` in `wget` refers to directory path where file has to  be downloaded
- `-O` or `--output-document` refers to save to directory with specific file name

If the `wget` command was used in some bash script you can `cat` the script and follow the same method

```
cat script.sh | grep "wget" | grep -E "(\-[PO])|(\-\-output-document|\-\-directory-prefix)"
```

from the output of that  you can figure out  where all the files downloaded using `wget` must have been stored.

Comment: Use `grep pattern file` instead of `cat file | grep pattern`, and save typing